# understand "-netdev" option in qemu

Tags: qemu

When I start `qemu` with `-device e1000,netdev=network0 -netdev tap,id=network0,ifname=tap299,script=no,downscript=no`, then am I correct that this `id=network0` creates an association between vNIC and network setup in host machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. Referring to the [documentation](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#How_to_create_a_network_backend.3F), this `id` is used to map the vNIC to its network backend on the host:

> The id option gives the name by which the virtual network device and the network backend are associated with each other. If you want multiple virtual network devices inside the guest they each need their own network backend. The name is used to distinguish backends from each other and must be used even when only one backend is specified.